# How to display an element over the top of another element?

Tags: css

I am trying to create a navigation bar with a tags, that when clicked, other a tags appear that were previously hidden. Then when the original a tag is clicked again the other a tags become invisible as they originally were.

I have tried searching on stack overflow, w3 schools and  using many different answers to try and solve the problem but with no success. Here is a screenshot of what it currently looks like when I hover over it http://puu.sh/gpyZO/155eff729b.png and this is what I want to happen http://puu.sh/gpz5U/7a4c57e093.png. So that the expanded a links are seen over the top of the other links beneath.

Here are the things I have tried in css: position (works but one tag overlaps other tags), display, visibility, overflow, clearfix.  I don't do a lot of styling with JavaScript but here is what I have tried: seeing if the value of hidden is equal to true then, changing it so it is opposite in an if/else if structure and vice versa.

HTML:

```
<nav class="down">
<section class="down"><a name="#" class="hidden"></a>
<a href="#" class="down test">Hi</a>
<a href="bye" id="show" class="xtra">This</a>
<a href="bye" class="xtra">is</a>
<a href="bye" class="xtra">expanded</a>
<a href="bye" class="xtra">link</a>
</section>
<a href="hi" class="down">My</a>
<a href="hi" class="down">Name</a>
<a href="hi" class="down">Is</a>
<a href="hi" class="down">Curtis</a>
<a href="hi" class="down">Good</a>
<a href="hi" class="down">Bye</a>
```

CSS:

```
a {
      background-attachment: fixed; */There is more code but this seems the only relevant bit/*
  }

nav {
margin-bottom: 20px;
text-align: left;
vertical-align: top;
}

.down {
width: 50px;
display: inline-block;
}

.hidden {
visibility: hidden;
display: block;
margin-bottom: -10px;
}

section.down a.xtra  {
vertical-align: top;
display: none;
visibility: hidden;
}

section.down:hover a.xtra  {
vertical-align: top;
display: block;
visibility: visible;
width: inherit;
background-color: rgb(50, 200, 50); 
}

a.down {
width: 50px;
display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: hey, you need to post your html and css.

Comment: cannot see you link, not so sure what exactly you want. But Z-INDEX maybe is what you need. But, jquery probably will do what you want too. If you had tried a lot of ways and it didn't work, then don't focus css because probally css cannot do it, go for javascript/jquery.

Comment: @conan, Thank you for the suggestion. I really hope I don't have to use JS because I am inexperienced in this area at least in changing the  styling of a web page. As with Jquery I have no prior experience.